# How to manage app permissionsfor the messenger on Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app that uses IBM Watson Conversation to respond questions of customers and want to add this app on Facebook, so it can work with the messenger for a page.

I already have this same app working on other pages, but this one page, where I have admin privileges is giving me head aches.

I can add the app to the page on Configurations -> Messenger Platform and I also can link the page to the app on the developers section, making a POST like this

```
POST/v2.12/page_id/subscribed_apps
```

Everything seems to happen properly.

When I access the Messenger Platform section again, the app is there, but it doesn't have all the permissions I need (the ones for work with the messenger).

Anyone can tell me if a page can have some configuration that sets the permissions that can be granted to an app?
Or even better, can I set the app permissions manually?

Comment: You are a "full" admin for the page - not one of the "lesser" roles, advertiser, etc.? What permissions are missing? Have you verified the admin user access token you used to acquire the page access token included them?

Comment: Yes, I'm listed with the Admin role. There are these permissions: manage_pages, pages_show_list, public_profile. On the other page, where everything works, the app has these permission: manage_pages, pages_show_list, pages_messaging, pages_messaging_phone_number, pages_messaging_subscriptions, public_profile

Comment: `pages_messaging_phone_number` is part of Customer Matching, I am not sure whether the restriction on the page admin being "US-based" applies only during review of the bot app itself, or if the pages you want to use it on later also require certain characteristics ...?